# Strange behavior on a js RegExp : one character not captured at the end

Tags: javascript, regex

I need help to understand why this happens :

I have a string in the form of `"'{{item}}'"` (notice the single quotes inside double quotes).
So I wrote two regular expressions in order to remove single quotes and braces :

- This one does not capture the last character : `/{{|}}|'{{|}}'/g` (result is `"item'"`)
- This one does : `/'{{|}}'|{{|}}/g` (result is `"item"`)

I tried to replace the single quote by a random character, but no matter, the last character is never captured in the first regex, while it is in the second. Why ?

Comment: Matches are prioritized in left-to-right order.

Comment: Just use `s.replace(/'{{|}}'/g, '')`. `{{|}}` is not necessary if you always have single quotes. If they are optional use `s.replace(/'?{{|}}'?/g, '')`.

Comment: Yes they are optional. The regex with "?" is perfect, thanks ! :D   As far as I understand, there is something wrong with closing double braces "}}" in regex, but I can't find why